# Python: unable to convert unicode to string

Tags: python

I've tried everything but the unicode just doesn't go away.

```
col = "[u'$929.95']"
unicoded_item = to_unicode(col) # [u'test']

print type(unicoded_item) # <type 'unicode'>
if isinstance(unicoded_item, unicode):
    unicoded_item = unicoded_item.encode('utf8')
    print str(unicoded_item) # [u'test']
```

I expected the whole `[u'` and `']` to disappear but it just doesn't seem to convert. So when I save this string to a text file, the text file will literally have all the unicode python character `[u'test']` is literally written instead of `test`

Comment: for clarification: do you get `[u'test']` or `u'test'`?

Comment: That's because you have what looks like the string representation of a _list_ not a string. What do you get when you type `print(col[0])`? A `t` or `test`?

Comment: @c909 yes getting `[u'test']`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid omg...I see, wondering why the type doesn't say 'list' however if it was a list

Comment: That's because you are doing `type(unicoded_item)`; when you did `unicoded_item = to_unicode(col)`, it took the _str representation of a list_ and then converted that to unicode. If you do `type(col)` you'll get the correct type.

Comment: You can answer it yourself and accept it to close the question :)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid actually the col is a 'string' that represents '
[u'$449.97']` for example

Comment: Why are you doing this type juggling anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a string that is the representation of a list object. The easiest way to get this thing sorted out, is to evaluate the string to get an object out:

```
>>> import ast
>>> col = "[u'$929.95']"
>>> col2 = ast.literal_eval(col)
>>> type(col)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(col2)
<type 'list'>
>>> col2[0]
u'$929.95'
>>> str(col2[0])
'$929.95'
```

Comment: the thing is sometimes the value col is clean meaning it's `$929.95`, I can't control what type of data ultimately makes it through so looks like I need to implement this

Answer (score 2):

The variable `col` probably contains a list with one unicode string element.

`unicoded_item = to_unicode(col)` then creates a unicode string with the representation of that list: `u"[u'test']"`.

You then convert this unicode string to a string using `unicoded_item.encode('utf8')`.

This gives you a (byte) string `"[u'test']"`.

The solution is to access the element(s) in `col` instead of converting the whole `col`. If `col` always contains exactly one element you can simply replace the uses of `col` with `col[0]`.

Comment: what I found was that col was already a string. it is not a list. so i was converting a string like `[u'$449.97']` into unicode fails. need to convert a string representation of a unicode, into unicode, and then back to string.

Comment: Ok, then please include more code in your next question. As you didn't provide the assignment resulting in `col` everyone here could only guess the reason for your result.

Comment: @c909 I have done that. I think I might just extract the stuff between the texts

Answer (score 1):

It may not deal with the issue directly, but you could use the *replace()* function to swap the `[u'` for nothing.

Comment: actually that's not a bad solution but I think the problem is dealing with the trailing `']`

Answer (score 0):

you string is not unicode. It is a regular string. You can get the dollar 
amount like this:

```
res = "[u'$929.95']".split("\'",)[1]
print(res)

$929.95
```

but if it were unicode with u'someletters, to remove u' ran str() on unicode str.
.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried and got ë. As for split, yes, it is a bad habit of mine always you re.split. But on a single delimiter re.split is redundant of course, so have changed thanks for you remark ot regular split.

Comment: python3 . OP tag states  python without a version