# Get the text between string like [u'$649.99']

Tags: python, regex

I have a python string that looks like this:

```
[u'$649.99']
```

I would like to use regex to pull out the `$649.99`.

The regex should look at the farthest `']` to make sure that the text doesn't accidentally get cut off.

I expect `$649.99`.

Comment: Is that really what your string looks like (including the brackets and the internal apostrophes), or is that a list containing one unicode string?

Comment: @DSM yes unfortunately that is literlaly the string directly. its a string that represents a list containig one unicode string....

Comment: This must be a homework problem. Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112431/python-unable-to-convert-unicode-to-string

Comment: The problem is, that this string exists. The solution is, not to write such strings.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that.

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "[u'$649.99']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
['$649.99']
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)[0]
'$649.99'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would look like

```
\$\d*\.\d\d$
```

which will take `$` followed by 0 or more digits, followed by a decimal `\.` escaped to make it literal, followed by two digits, at the end of the string. Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kV4wX1/2)

Comment: This doesn't inlcude the "$", which was requested I believe.

Comment: That $ at the end is actually incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you want is:

```
/'(.*)'/
```

which is everything between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be

```
regex = re.compile(r"\[u'(.*)'\]")
result = regex.match("[u'$649.99']").group(0)
```

Please note that this only works if the unicode string that got mangled into a string representation contains no special chars, `'` or `\`.

If that may be the case, a Python literal parser like [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) would be a better way to get the contents of the string representation.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you don't really need Regex for that. You can use `str()` functino to convert unicode string in your list into a normal string:

```
a = "[u'$649.99']" 
str(eval(a)[0])
```

but if you want Regex this will do it

```
r'\$\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you don't need to import anything:

```
>>> s = "[u'$649.99']"
>>> s.split("'")[1]
'$649.99'
```